# How to shade the upper contour set of a function (pgfplots, tikzpicture)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

I would like to shade the entire area above the function f(x) = 0.5/x, over the entire domain of the function (that is 0.5:47 in my case) up to y=1.
In other words, I'm looking to fill/**shade the upper contour set of my function**.

Here's the code I use:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        axis lines = left,
        xlabel = \(a\),
        xlabel style={xshift=7.7cm, yshift=0.8cm,},
        ylabel = {$\alpha$},
        ylabel style={xshift=4cm, yshift=-1.2cm, rotate=-90,},
        ymode=log,
        yminorgrids=true,
        xmax=47,
        xmin=0.1,
        width=16cm,
        height=9cm,
        ytick={0.01, 0.1, 1.0},
        yticklabels={{$0.01$}, {$0.1$},{$1.0$}},
]

\addplot[name path = A, domain=0:47, samples=100, red] {0.5/x}
node [pos=0.95, above] {$\small{\textcolor{red}{\alpha= \frac{0.5}{a}}}$};
\path[name path=axiss] (0,1) -- (50,1); 

\addplot fill between[
    of = A and axiss, 
    soft clip={domain=0.5:47},
    every even segment/.style  = {gray,opacity=.4}
 ];

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here's the result I get:

[image: weird shaded area]

However, I would have to get something like this:
[image: upper contour set]

N.B: I also tried with:`\addplot[name path = A, domain=0:47, samples=100, red, fill=grey] {0.5/x}` however the result looks more like the epigraph rather than the upper contour set of my function (since the shaded area doesn't go up to y=1 over the entire domain 0.5:47).

Using my function, and roughly roughly drawn, I would like to have this instead:
[image: upper contour set my function]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost had it.

- remove/comment `soft clip` from `fill between` options
- add `split` to the `fill between` options

```
% used PGFPlots v1.18.1
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=left,
        xlabel=\(a\),
        xlabel style={xshift=7.7cm, yshift=0.8cm,},
        ylabel={$\alpha$},
        ylabel style={xshift=4cm, yshift=-1.2cm, rotate=-90,},
        ymode=log,
        yminorgrids=true,
        xmax=47,
        xmin=0.1,
        width=16cm,
        height=9cm,
        ytick={0.01, 0.1, 1.0},
        yticklabels={{$0.01$}, {$0.1$},{$1.0$}},
    ]

        \addplot [name path=A, domain=0:47, samples=100, red] {0.5/x}
            node [pos=0.95, above] {$\small{\textcolor{red}{\alpha= \frac{0.5}{a}}}$};
        \path [name path=axiss] (0,1) -- (50,1);

        \addplot fill between [
            of=A and axiss,
            split,
%            soft clip={domain=0.5:47},
            every even segment/.style={gray,opacity=.4},
        ];

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: +1. But, perhaps it would be better to change the `axiss` path domain? Something like `\path [name path=axiss] (0.5,1) -- (47,1);`. There is an annoying little gray filling at the top left corner. :-)

Comment: This removes the top left fill: `\addplot fill between [of=A and axiss, split, every segment no 0/.style={green,opacity=0.4}];`

Comment: @hpekristiansen, had found that myself, but updating the answer took a bit longer ;)

Comment: @hpekristiansen, interestingly it is segment `0`. I would have thought that the top left corner is segment 0 and the big one/the one of interest is segment 1. Actually I didn't find the segment of the top left corner ... did you?

Comment: @Stefan Pinnow: No. I do not understand how it works. Most of my answers are just me reading the manual and trying something until it by accident works.

Comment: @StefanPinnow: If I use `1`, the main area(`0`) becomes red - even though I have no `red` in my code!?

Comment: With more samples(e.g. 1000), the upper left area are more "real" and can be selected with `0` as expected.